# How to extract big mgrs using regex

Tags: regex

I have an input json:

{"id":12345,"mgrs":"04QFJ1234567890","code":"12345","user":"db3e1a-3c88-4141-bed3-206a"}

I would like to extract with regular expression MGRS of 1000 kilometer, in my example result should be: 04QFJ1267

First 2 symbols always digits, next 3 always chars and the rest always digits. MGRS have a fix length of 15 chars at all.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? And what does the "1000 kilometer"s have to do with it?

Comment: How would the input designate that the mgrs are of 1000 km?

Comment: I always have mgrs with length 15 on input (this is 1 meter mgrs resolution) and always I need to convert to mgrs of 1000 kilometer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system

Comment: You should be able to parse the JSON and check if `mgrs="04QFJ1267"`, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is remove characters 8-10 and 13-15.  If you want/need to do that using regex, then you could use the replace method with regex:  (**EDIT** Edited to remove the rest of the string).

```
 .*?(\w{7})\d{3}(\d{2})\d+.*
```

and replacement string:

```
$1$2
```

I see now you are using Java.  So the relevant code line might look like:

```
resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(".*?(\\w{7})\\d{3}(\\d{2})\\d+.*", "$1$2");
```

The above assumes all your strings look like what you showed, and there is no need to test to be sure that "mgrs" is in the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I do MGRS 1000 km extraction without replacement operation with regex in one line?

Comment: You could use a similar regex along with multiple capturing groups to extract just those that are relevant to what you require.  But why in the world would you want to do that when the replace method is so much simpler?  Perhaps this is a homework assignment?